# Continuously How to insert data in SQL Server 2012 from one server database to another server database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have two databases in two servers.

```
Server1 - DB1 - TableA
Server2 - DB2 - TableB
```

Whenever the user punches the access in Swiping machine, then it will be updated in Server1.DB1.TableA. I have only one Database option in my swiping machine. So I need to update the TableA data from Server1 to Server2 TableB.

Whenever a new record inserted in TableA, then it has be inserted automatically in Server2.DB2.TableB. How can I achieve this. Please help me out.

Comment: if you can show us the statement you have already tried then it will be easier to help you.:)

Comment: Are you looking for Replication?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have a look at transactional replication for this task.

There are a lot of resources available on this, here is a good start for an overview:

[SQL Server Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Set up Server2 as a Linked Server on Server1 (using SSMS under Server Objects > Linked Servers). You can then add an Insert trigger to TableA which inserts to TableB on the linked server:

```
insert into Server2.DB2.dbo.TableB(columns....etc etc
```

Not as heavy as Replication, if this is all you want to do.

Cheers -

Comment: Of course, doing an insert to server 2 from a trigger from server 1 ties the servers together such that if *either* server is down, the insert cannot succeed on server 1.